# Meteor Slingshot upload to Amazon S3

Tags: meteor, meteor-slingshot

I'm new to this package, and to Amazon S3.
I've followed the instructions on the main page of the slingshot package, setup a new s3 bucket, configured the credentials in Meteor.settings, configured a CORS file on the bucket, all looks ok.
But when I call uploader.send (with the sample code from the package main page), I get the following error on the console, and the file is not uploaded:

```
Error uploading <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>...
```

Am I missing something? Anyone able to help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with the s3 user permissions setup.
The user to which the credentials are stored in the settings file must have access to store files in the bucket. The easiest way (for test only) is to grant the user the S3 Full Access policy.

Comment: Could you explain how you did this? Did you use security credentials or create an IAM user? I'm using Security Credentials and getting the same error you did.